# Trying to display live table which is editable using ajax and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have four different files

```
index.php
select.php
insert.php
edit.php
delete.php
```

In my backend I have created a database named 'ecc'

Database 'ecc' has atable named 'task'

The table task has following fields

id, name, category, cost

Datatype for id set to int and index as primary also id field is on auto increment

My Issue:My code is only displaying 'Live Table Data'.

It would be grate if someone rewrite it or suggest some changes.

***index.php***

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <h3 align="center">Live Table Add Edit Delete using Ajax Jquery in PHP Mysql</h3><br />  
                     <div id="live_data"></div>                 
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  

 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#live_data').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  

 fetch_data();  
      $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function(){  

           var name = $('#name').text();  
           var category = $('#category').text();
           var cost = $('#cost').text();

           if(name == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter Service Name");  
                return false;  
           }  

           if(category == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter Category of Service");  
                return false;  
           }  

           if(cost == '')  
           {  
                alert("Enter cost");  
                return false;  
           }  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"insert.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{name:name, category:category, cost:cost},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     fetch_data();  
                }  
           })  
      });  
      function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"edit.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
                dataType:"text",  
                success:function(data){  
                     alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }  
      $(document).on('blur', '.name', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id1");  
           var name = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id, name, "name");  
      });  
      $(document).on('blur', '.category', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id2");  
           var category = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id,category, "category"); 

      $(document).on('blur', '.cost', function(){  
           var id = $(this).data("id3");  
           var category = $(this).text();  
           edit_data(id,cost, "cost"); 
      });  

      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
           var id=$(this).data("id4");  
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"delete.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{id:id},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data){  
                          alert(data);  
                          fetch_data();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

***select.php***

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecc");  
 $output = '';  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM task ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                     <th width="40%">First Name</th>  
                     <th width="40%">Last Name</th>  
                     <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
                </tr>';  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                     <td class="name" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="category" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["category"].'</td>
                     <td class="cost" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["cost"].'</td>
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '  
           <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td id="name" contenteditable></td>  
                <td id="category" contenteditable></td> 
                <td id="cost" contenteditable></td> 
                <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                     </tr>';  
 }  
 $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

***insert.php***

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test_db");  
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_sample(name, category, cost) VALUES('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["category"]."', '".$_POST["cost"]."')";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Inserted';  
 }  
 ?>
```

***edit.php***

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecc");  
 $id = $_POST["id"];  
 $text = $_POST["text"];  
 $column_name = $_POST["column_name"];  
 $sql = "UPDATE task SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE id='".$id."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Updated';  
 }  
 ?>
```

***delete.php***

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ecc");  
 $sql = "DELETE FROM task WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
      echo 'Data Deleted';  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use data tables for this, no need of all this

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

check this, data tables provide libraries for this